# PowerShell script to output SQL query results

Tags: sql-server, powershell

I have the SQL cmdlets loaded in PowerShell, need a script to execute a  SQL statements and save results in pipe delimited file

Answer (score 2):

You can output to a pipe-delimited file by piping the output to `Export-Csv` and specifying the delimiter as a pipe.

```
invoke-sqlcmd -ServerInstance <server_name> -Database <database_name> -query "<query>" `
| Export-Csv -Delimiter "|" -Path "U:\temp\export.csv"
```

Comment: thanks for the push I was almost there

Comment: thanks for the push I was almost there, is there a parameter for the column headings?

Comment: duh sorry headings are there is there a way to remove the headed #TYPE System.Data.DataRow at the top of data set?

Comment: Try -NoTypeInformation switch on the Export-Csv command.